# Convert Float to String without losing precision - Java

Tags: java

I want to convert a Float number to String without losing its precision.

When I convert **40075016.68557849** to String, it is being represented as **4.0075016E7**.

I need to get it represented exactly as the entered value, that is "**40075016.68557849**".

I've tried String.valueOf(), Float(40075016.68557849f).toString() but nothing is working in the proper way.

Comment: Try entering your number here https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html then you will see that you lose the precision, because float is not capable of storing the number.

Comment: First, that's too many digits for a `float` (or a `Float`); you'd need to use a `double` (or `Double`).  Second, `float` and `double` are not, in general,  capable of _exact_ representations of decimal factions (except those which happen to be multiples of a negative power of 2).  If you need exact representations of arbitrary decimal fractions, you need `BigDecimal`.

Comment: `40075016.68557849f` is already imprecise. Nothing to do with `Float.toString()` at all. Try `BigDecimal.valueOf("40075016.68557849").toString()`.

Comment: For curious one: this magic number is equatorial Earth circumference in meters.

Answer (score 1):

## `BigDecimal`

If you need to maintain your fractional number precisely, you cannot use the floating-point types `float`/`Float` and `double`/`Double`. Floating-point technology [trades away accuracy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic#Accuracy_problems) for speed of execution. And there are limits to the size of numbers they can hold.

Instead use [`BigDecimal`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html). Much slower but accurate.

```
new BigDecimal( "40075016.68557849" )
```

Comment: It is important that you use a string in the constructor here.

Answer (score 0):

If the number does not have to be human-readable then you can use `Double.doubleToLongBits()` and `Double.longBitsToDouble()` and then print the long. This preserves the *exact* bit pattern of the value. In particular, it preserves the exact pattern of a NaN, in case that is important.

Another option may be `Double.toHexString()`.

If the number needs to be human readable then check [this document](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html#1251). It explains that printing to 17 decimal digits (`%.17g` or `%.17f`) is enough to guarantee that reading back the string will produce the same number.